# How do i use the distinct function in microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Am trying to select data from two tables: the product table and the stock_in table and i dont seem to be getting it. so in server, am querying all products have added in my database and the amount of quantity from the stock_in table.
so when the stock got exhausted, i have to purchase that same product again. so after purchasing that product. what is the problem? the problem is that am using inner join

```
SELECT DISTINCT add_new_product.product_code, 
                add_new_product.product_name, 
                add_new_product.barcode, 
                add_new_product.sales_rate, 
                add_new_product.discount, 
                add_new_product.vat, 
                stock_in.stock, 
                stock_in.available 
FROM   add_new_product 
       LEFT JOIN stock_in 
              ON add_new_product.product_code = stock_in.product_code
```

and this is what is returning :

```
product_code   product_name   barcode    sales_rate   discount   vat   stock   Available
PR-01           Book200       QWER1234     600           0        0      20    Yes
PR-01           Book200       QWER1234     600           0        0      25    Yes
PR-02           Book500       QW23         700           0        0      10    Yes
```

but this is not what i want to achieve, i want to select just one product code which is PR-01 and the recent stock from stock_in table. am testing this from ms SQL before using it in my application but am not getting it yet. am not sure if my query is right considering the stock column having different values. I hope you all understand this, Thanks. So the actual data i want to retrieve is this

```
product_code   product_name   barcode    sales_rate   discount   vat   stock   Available
PR-01           Book200       QWER1234     600           0        0      25    Yes
PR-02           Book500       QW23         700           0        0      10    Yes
```

not the previous data. Thanks.

Comment: You aren't asking for distinct records, you're asking for either the maximum stock value or the latest based on some (unspecified) sort order. There's no implicit order in relational databases so there's nothing that says what the latest stock value is here

Comment: What data or column represents "recent stock" in stock_in table, is it a date, or maybe an incremented primary key?

Comment: @Iztoksson the recent stock i mean here is using order by desc, like going to stock_in table to get the last stock for that product code

Comment: If you want the maximum, use `GROUP BY` and `MAX(stock)`. If you want the latest, you can use `LAST_VALUE(stock) OVER(partition by product_Code ORDER BY someColumn)` to get the first value in each row, then use `GROUP BY` to eliminate duplicates

Comment: @Haywhy order by what? There's no column in this question that could be used for sorting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if there is any help you can render, have displayed up there what i acutally want, if you know any other means, Plz help

Comment: @Haywhy I already commented that there's no sort order in this question. You can't tell by looking at the data whether the stock is 20 or 25. Is there a date column or an ID that could be used for ordering

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos said - what is the column you want to ORDER BY DESC?

Comment: stock, the stock value. the stock is a different table while the rest are same tables

Comment: How can you order by column `stock` and get last valid value? Usually stock depletes with time so the stock value should decrease, if you order it by descending then you will always get the first value that was stored into the database.

Comment: @Haywhy you can't order by stock. This will only return the `MAX` or `MIN` value. A **human** can't tell whether the last stock value is 20 or 25 without checking *something* like an ID or date column to determine the order, or knowing whether the display order was tied to some other column. Again, there's **no order** in a relational database and rows can be returned in *any* order unless you explicitly sort them

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable(product_code varchar(10),product_name varchar(10),
>                      barcode varchar(10),sales_rate int,discount int,vat int,
>                      stock int,availability varchar(3))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO MyTable(product_code,product_name,barcode,sales_rate,discount,vat,stock,
> availability) VALUES ('PR-01','Book200','QWER1234',600,0,0,20,'Yes'),
> ('PR-01','Book200','QWER1234',600,0,0,25,'Yes'),
> ('PR-02','Book500','QWE23',700,0,0,10,'Yes')
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT product_code,product_name
>        ,barcode,sales_rate,discount,availability
>       ,MAX(stock) as stock FROM MyTable
> GROUP BY product_code,product_name
>        ,barcode,sales_rate,discount,availability
> ```
>
> ```
> product_code | product_name | barcode  | sales_rate | discount | availability | stock
> :----------- | :----------- | :------- | ---------: | -------: | :----------- | ----:
> PR-01        | Book200      | QWER1234 |        600 |        0 | Yes          |    25
> PR-02        | Book500      | QWE23    |        700 |        0 | Yes          |    10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c51fd0268187ed4347f7a3d4b98cb36)*

Comment: The OP is asking for the "last" stock value, not the maximum. It's impossible to determine this from just the columns in the question

Comment: A code-only answer (i.e., without any explanation) is not a teaching-tool and does not help OP understand the issues with their own work nor improve knowledge of tsql.